# ElectronJS: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I've just started learning Electron from [Electron Docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start). I used ES6 `(import/export)` while they used `require`.

I've added `type:module` in my `package.json` and also I've changed the `js` extension to `mjs`, but each time I run `npm start` ( My node version => 14 ), I get this error:

```
App threw an error during load
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/alaeddine/Desktop/electron-app/petro-book/main.mjs
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:11)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at loadApplicationPackage (/Users/alaeddine/Desktop/electron-app/petro-book/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:110:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alaeddine/Desktop/electron-app/petro-book/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:222:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1108:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:935:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
```

**Package.json:**

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "petro-book",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Menai Ala Eddine",
  "description": "Desktop application for gas stations",
  "main": "main.mjs",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.mjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.7"
  }
}
```

**Main.mjs:**

```js
import { app, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import { join } from "path";

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  win.loadFile("index.html");
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(selector);
    if (element) element.innerText = text;
  };

  for (const type of ["chrome", "node", "electron"]) {
    replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there no answer?

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21457#issuecomment-1099904505)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to load esm in your node_modules.

$ npm install esm --save

Put below config in your configuration. This is in my case:

```
  "main": "src/index.cjs",
  "module" : "src/main.mjs",
  "type": "module",
```

Put Your main script to open window in **main.mjs** (using es6 style).

here is **index.cjs** as startup:

```
require = require("esm")(module/* , options */)
module.exports = require("./main.mjs")
```

and our main part in **main.mjs**

```
import electron from 'electron';
import path from 'path';

const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

function createWindow() {
  ....
}
```

Check in here https://arahutara.wordpress.com/2022/07/13/using-es6-import-in-electron-apps/

Hopes this will help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Does esm allow use of named imports?

Comment: esm hasn't been updated in 4 years. It feels like there should be a better solution to this by now...