# Electron Tasklist Error : require() of ES Module not supported

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to create an Electron app that lists currently running processes using [TaskList](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tasklist).
I'm currently quite new to Electron and NodeJS so I'm unfamiliar with the errors and import vs require.

I've already gone through the resolve in ["Error: require() of ES modules is not supported when importing node-fetch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041454/error-require-of-es-modules-is-not-supported-when-importing-node-fetch) as you'll see I've attempted to use this in my code.

package.json

```json
{
    "type": "module",
    "name": "task-list",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "Hilton Siegert",
    "description": "Task List",
    "main": "src/index.cjs",
    "module": "src/main.mjs",
    "devDependencies": {
        "esm": "^3.2.25",
        "electron": "^26.2.0",
        "tasklist": "^5.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron ."
    }
}
```

main.mjs

```js
import electron from 'electron';
import path from "path";
import url from "url";

import {tasklist} from 'tasklist'; 
tasklist.then(function(data){ 
    console.log(data); 
}); 

// const tasklist = (...args) => import('tasklist').then(({default: tasklist}) => tasklist(...args));
// tasklist().then(function(data){ 
//  console.log(data); 
// }).catch(function(error){
//  console.log(error); 
// }); 

const __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

let win; 
function createWindow(){
    win = new BrowserWindow(); 
    win.loadURL(url.format({ 
        "pathname": path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
        "protocol": "file", 
        "slashes": true,
        "autoHideMenuBar": true,
    })); 
    
    win.setMenu(null); 
    win.webContents.openDevTools(); 
    
    win.on("closed", function(){
        win = null; 
    }); 
}; 

app.on("ready", function(){
    createWindow(); 
}); 

app.whenReady().then(function(){ 
    createWindow(); 
    app.on("activate", function(){ 
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) 
            createWindow(); 
    }); 
}); 

app.on("window-all-closed", function(){ 
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") 
        app.quit(); 
});
```

index.cjs

```js
require = require("esm")(module/* , options */); 
module.exports = require("./main.js");
```

I have also tried using the [esm moduel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) using [these](https://arahutara.wordpress.com/2022/07/13/using-es6-import-in-electron-apps/) instructions that were suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443778/electronjs-must-use-import-to-load-es-module).